# Solr query for alphabetical search

Tags: solr

I have a solr-4.5.1, I need to get the results in alphabetical order, eg.. I have recipe title like (aa,abc,acb,ava,bca). I tried with the below params(q=&RecipeTitle=a*&fields=RecipeTitle) but its not giving the expected results. 
NOTE: recipe title is not stored.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sort parameter in query and solr will return alphabetically 
ordered results

```
q=*&fl=RecipeTitle&sort=RecipeTitle+asc
```

Query to get results starting with a :

```
q=*&fq=RecipeTitle:a*&fl=RecipeTitle&sort=RecipeTitle+asc
```