# Solr alphabetical search

Tags: solr

I have a requirement searching data from the solr in alphabetical order.. eg..

`"aaa,aba,abc,bba"` this is my query `"q=&fields=viewername&viewername=a*"`.
I am not getting proper result. I am getting whichever the document contains `"a"`.

Ex Results:

```
1.abcd-terstttttttttttttttt
2.aaab
3.Iraq: India wastes Army's Special Forces resource
```

but I need only the document which starts with `"a"`.

s`chema.xml`-`dynamicfield` is

```
dynamicField name="*_string" type="lowerstring" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="false"
```

If I change the type from "lowerstring"  to "string" and re-index, I am getting correct results. but I can not re-index all the records, because there's hundreds of thousands of them.

Comment: isnt this same question asked by you ...?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36642082/solr-query-for-alphabetical-search

Comment: can you share what all tokenizer and filters "lowerstring" has?

Comment: This is the tokenizer i have.. 
<fieldType name="lowerstring" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true">
    <analyzer type="index">
<tokenizer class="solr.WhiteSpaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer> 
      <analyzer type="query">
<tokenizer class="solr.WhiteSpaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
</fieldType>

Comment: Then in this case you need to change the fieldType to string...because the above fieldType will create the token...as you are using WhiteSpaceTokenizerFactory....Thats whats I have mentioned in my answer

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the result for `string` `fieldType` because when you have `field` of type String .. it does not get tokenized. Rather there wont be any token created for the input field.

But when you use any other fieldType which consists of tokenizers and filter it creates some tokens based on whats been used..

You can analyse the same in the `solr` admin page.

Depending on the same you can define the `fieldType` for a field.